# Applying MoCap face data to "foreign face"

Tags: animation, motion-capture

I recently modelled Gustavo Fring and I want to test Motion Capturing on him. So I painted a few dots on my face and took a short film.

Motion Tracking in Blender gave me these results:
[image]

Now I can transform this MoCap data to moving emptys and give them depth trough the face mesh. The problem is that Gus Fring has obviously other facial proportions.

[image]

So I request a way to move the empty while they are keeping their MoCap-movement.

[image]

Now Emyptys control the movement of the bones, but when I join the bones it it one amarture and cant be influenced by multple emptys, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need 2 rigs. And copy motion from first to second in local space using constraints.

Comment: Could you explain further how I can copy the motion